# Dealing with filtering a column with both numbers and strings using the panda query method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
def filter_dataframe(dataframe, column, numbers, strings=None):
    number_query = f"({column} >= {numbers[0]} and {column} <= {numbers[1]})"
    if strings is not None:
        single_string_query_list = []
        for string in strings:
            single_string_query = f"({column} == '{string}')"
            single_string_query_list.append(single_string_query)
        if len(strings) == 1:
            string_query = f"{' or '.join(single_string_query_list)}"
        else:
            string_query = f"({' or '.join(single_string_query_list)})"
        
        full_query = number_query + " or " + string_query
    else:
         full_query = number_query
    dataframe = dataframe.query(full_query)
    return dataframe
```

I am writing a function `filter_dataframe` that allows you to filter a specific dataframe by the values in a specific column. In particular, a column that contains both strings a numbers. The `numbers` parameter should be a list in the form `[min value, max value]` and the `strings` parameter should be a list of the string values you want. For example, let's say that I want to filter the below dataframe based on the values inside the "Numbers" column

```
             Numbers
0            1
1            2
2            3
3            4
4            5
5            6
6            "example 1"
7            7
8            "example 2"
9            "example 3"
10           8
```

which is created by the below code

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, "example 1", 7, "example 2", "example 3", 8]
df = pd.DataFrame(numbers, columns=["Numbers"])
```

and I want only the rows that have a number between 1 and 6 inclusive or contain the string "example 1" or "example 2". Assuming that `filter_dataframe` works, then we would execute

```
filter_dataframe(dataframe = df, column = "Numbers", numbers = [1,6], strings = ["example 1", "example 2"])
```

Essentially what happens inside `filter_dataframe` is it generates a pandas query (which is stored in the local variable `full_query`) which looks something like `"(Numbers >= 1 and Numbers <= 6) or ((Numbers == 'example 1') or (Numbers == 'example 2'))"`.

Obviously, because there are both strings and integers in the column, we will run into the error `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`. I know this function isn't greatly written, but are there any ideas on how work around this error?

Answer (score 0):

Create a temp column, with numeric type.
Set it equal to your query column, or `NaN` where
you find a string.

Now your `.query(...)` is a disjunct between
a fast range query on the numeric column,
and `str` set membership on the original column.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `query`, boolean indexing should be easier:

```
def filter_dataframe(dataframe, column, numbers, strings=None):
    if strings is None:
        strings = []

    return dataframe[pd.to_numeric(dataframe[column], errors='coerce')
                       .between(*numbers)
                    | dataframe[columns].isin(strings)]
```